# Query or Expression for excluding certain values from DAL selection

Tags: google-app-engine, data-access-layer, web2py

I'm trying to exclude posts which have a tag named meta from my selection, by:

```
meta_id = db(db.tags.name == "meta").select().first().id
not_meta = ~db.posts.tags.contains(meta_id)
posts=db(db.posts).select(not_meta)
```

But those posts still show up in my selection.

What is the right way to write that expression?

My tables look like:

```
db.define_table('tags',
    db.Field('name', 'string'),
    db.Field('desc', 'text', default="")
)

db.define_table('posts', 
    db.Field('title', 'string'),
    db.Field('message', 'text'),
    db.Field('tags', 'list:reference tags'),
    db.Field('time', 'datetime', default=datetime.utcnow())
)
```

I'm using Web2Py 1.99.7 on GAE with High Replication DataStore on Python 2.7.2

**UPDATE:**

I just tried `posts=db(not_meta).select()` as suggested by @Anthony, but it gives me a Ticket with the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 205, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "E:/Programming/Python/web2py/applications/vote_up/controllers/default.py", line 391, in <module>
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 173, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "E:/Programming/Python/web2py/applications/vote_up/controllers/default.py", line 8, in index
    posts=db(not_meta).select()#orderby=settings.sel.posts, limitby=(0, settings.delta)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 7578, in select
    return adapter.select(self.query,fields,attributes)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 3752, in select
    (items, tablename, fields) = self.select_raw(query,fields,attributes)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 3709, in select_raw
    filters = self.expand(query)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 3589, in expand
    return expression.op(expression.first)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\web2py\gluon\dal.py", line 3678, in NOT
    raise SyntaxError, "Not suported %s" % first.op.__name__
SyntaxError: Not suported CONTAINS
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As `~` isn't currently working on GAE with Datastore, I'm using the following as a temporary work-around:

```
meta = db.posts.tags.contains(settings.meta_id)
all=db(db.posts).select()#, limitby=(0, settings.delta)
meta=db(meta).select()
posts = []
i = 0
for post in all:
    if i==settings.delta: break
    if post in meta: continue
    else:
        posts.append(post)
        i += 1
#settings.delta is an long integer to be used with limitby
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
meta_id = db(db.tags.name == "meta").select().first().id
not_meta = ~db.posts.tags.contains(meta_id)
posts = db(not_meta).select()
```

First, your initial query returns a complete Row object, so you need to pull out just the "id" field. Second, `not_meta` is a Query object, so it goes inside `db(not_meta)` to create a Set object defining the set of records to select (the `select()` method takes a list of fields to return for each record, as well as a few other arguments, such as `orderby`, `groupby`, etc.).

Comment: Truly sorry @Anthony, I missed `.id` in my question although I'm using it in my code.

Comment: I just tried `db(not_meta).select()` but it gives me an error saying `<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> Not suported CONTAINS
`

Comment: It appears you are on Google App Engine. The problem is actually with the `~` (NOT) operator -- it is not supported on GAE.

Comment: You are right, it works fine without the `~`. Any known workarounds?